# Reducing size of res folder in Android (Multi-language Support)

Tags: android, string, android-resources, multilingual

My android application has `strings.xml` file of 1 MB. My employer wants to add support to 20 more languages in our app, which will thus cause the `APK` size to increase by 19 MB, which is not at all acceptable.

What can I do to reduce the size of the `APK`?

Is there any provision by which I can download `strings.xml` file for only those languages that the user wants to use on run-time from a server to my app data directory and use it in my app?

Or is there any other efficient way around?

N.B.: The app's `Minimum SDK` version is `19`. Also, I am not worried about other resources. I am just worried about large `string.xml` files.

Comment: `which will thus cause the APK size to increase by 19 MB`. No. Don't believe that as the apk is a zip file. So it will not increase by 1MB for every file. You can easily check this.

Comment: @greenapps it wont increase by exact 19 MB, but it will surely increase the size by a significant amount.

Comment: How much you think? Or experimented? Please be exact.

Comment: I can't give an exact estimate of the size as of now. My current APK size is around 15 MB. Given that there will be 19 more xml files of 1 MB each in the apk, even though the files in APK are compressed, I expect my APK size to increase by atleast around 10 MB. So the size will be 167% of the current size.

Comment: My god just put some copies of that file in that folder and you know. You should already have done that before asking.

Comment: Its jumping from 15 MB to 26 MB.

Comment: Well your calculation was pretty good then! ;-).

Comment: Yeah! Might be a little less since I had other changes in the code as well. Do you know how I can tackle this hurdle?

Comment: Sorry. Not at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the size of apk you can use optimized png image in you application based on the type of device your application will support. Delete all the unwanted resource and library in your application. Apart from that you can use Proguard it will automatically reduce the size of apk.

Refer:
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I am worried about the size of `string.xml` file for the supported languages. I have already removed unused resources, used all png images, and also using `proguard`. I have also used `minifyEnabled true` and `shrinkResources true` in `build.gradle`.

Comment: To minimise the string I think you should release different apk for different locale. It can be managed from google play developer console.

Comment: Yes, I know that can be done. But we are not looking to release separate build per language. We want the user to be able to switch languages without having to download different APKs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to analyse your apk.

Android studio give the functionality analyse your apk.

You need to go to option at following path Build>>Analyze APK..

It will give you the result where you can check which folder occupies how much space.From that you can evaluate and can reduce the size of the apk

Comment: Please read the question carefully.

I know where the size is increasing. As I said in my question that my `strings.xml` is 1 MB. When I will add support for 19 other languages, each language will have their own `strings.xml` of 1 MB each, which will add 19 MB (or somewhere close to that) to the APK size. I need the solution for that.